# Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading Multiple Has Many Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

In my DB the model `Class` has many `Student` and every `Student` has many `Homework` and every `Homework` has many `Question`. How can I write a single query with eager loading to get every `Question` that is related to one specific `Class`?

I can get a nested structure with this code:

```
$class = Class::find($classId);
$collection = $class->with('students.homeworks.questions')->get();
```

How can I get the array of all questions in this collection? What I get currently with `toArray()` method is a structure like this:

```
{ //Class
    ...
    students: [
        {
            homeworks: [
                {
                    questions: [{...}]
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post your code thus far of your attempt. Stackoverlow is not a code writing service nor a tutorial service. We are here to help with code issues and without the code, we can't do anything. Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Ok. Added the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```
class Class extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Question::class, [Student::class, Homework::class]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great and as far as I can tell judging by the footprint on laravel debugbar query tab, it's very efficient and economic too. I think this should be part of laravel's future release.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function within the Students model:

```
public function questions(){
   $questions = [];
   foreach($this->homework as $homework){
        foreach($homework->questions as $question){
           array_push($questions, $question);
        }
   }
   return $questions;
}
```

This way every time you have an student object you can get an array of all the questions like this:

```
$student->questions
```

Hope this could help you.